# If $X=\{x\}$, then $\dim(X)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $X$ is a quasiprojective variety, then by definition $\dim(X)=trdeg(k(X)|k)$.

I'm trying to prove if $X=\{x\}$ is a point, then $\dim(X)=0$

I'm already proved that $k[X]\cong k$, now if I prove $k(X)\cong k[X]$, I'm done.

I'm almost sure it's just a simple argument, if someone has some idea or hint how to proceed I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This "definition" is rather a characterization which holds in that very special case. See any good text on algebraic geometry which gives the correct definition of the dimension, measuring the lengths of chains of irreducible closed subsets. In any case it is trivial that a point is $0$-dimensional ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg yes, I know, the book I'm using is based on Shafarevich's book which defines dim(X) as trdeg(k(X)|k) and leaves the usual definition using lengths of chains as a theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$k(X)$ is the field of fractions of $k[X].$ What is the field of fractions of the field $k?$

Comment: I don't know, $k$ itself? why?

Comment: Of course it's isomorphic to $k$, since $k$ is a field. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

That's not the usual definition of dimension. What you state as a definition is probably a theorem to most people.

If you're familiar with the usual definition, then it's pretty clear that the maximal chain of irreducible closed subsets of $\{x\}$ is just the one-step chain $\{x\}$.

Comment: yes, I know, the book I'm using is based on Shafarevich's book which defines dim(X) as trdeg(k(X)|k) and leaves the usual definition as a theorem.